# Is “get somebody off the couch” a well-established idiom?

Tags: phrases

I found the phrase, “*get (sb.) off the couch*” in the headline of the article of Time.com (June 24) and also in a caption of YouTube. Each reads:

- Jobless graduates: Six ways to *get your kid off the couch*, into a good job. – Time.com
- At eDiets Live Jillian Michaels speaks to a woman on how to *get off the couch*. – YouTube.

From the context of the lines, I can easily guess it means to let someone rise up from the couch to start to do something or to work, but I don’t find “*get off the couch*” as an idiom in dictionaries at hand, neither in Free Merriam Webster nor Cambridge Dictionary online. 
Is this well-received idiom? Did it come from a title of song?

Comment: You may find this question relevant: _[What is the origin of the term “Couch Potato”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/29330/5822)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Get off the couch" is a derisive command to stop whatever useless thing you were just doing and start doing what you *should* be doing. It is most often used literally:

> Get off the couch! Go take out the trash!
>
> Ugh, all you do is watch TV. Get off the couch...

A similar idiom is "get off the bench" which refers to sports athletes who spend most of the game sitting on the players' bench instead of on the field.

> Get off the bench and into the game!

The implication in both idioms is that the first step toward being useful involves *getting off your ass* and getting *on your feet* — both of which are also idioms. The entire concept has many sayings that invoke the same feelings of (a) shame for being on the couch/bench/your ass and (b) pressure to perform.

Comment: One small quibble: couch potatoes are on the couch *voluntarily*; athletes are generally on the bench *involuntarily* - due to injury, misconduct, or simply not being as good as the starting lineup.  Coaches - at any level higher than grammar school - usually don't have to yell at their players to get off the bench; pro athletes would *rather* be in the game.

Comment: @MT_Head: Agreed. They are similar but not the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly common. As you suggested, the idea is that lazy people are on the couch watching TV instead of doing something productive. Related is the term "couch potato," meaning a lazy person. I don't think it comes from a song or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an idiomatic expression, but its derived from an expression, "Couch Potato".

A "couch potato" is a lazy person, who sits on the couch and watches tv, and presumeably eating, so the headlines "Six ways to get your kids off the couch, into a good job." basically means "Six ways to make your kids stop being lazy, and into a good job."

The other headlines, in eDiets, refers to the same expression(Couch potato) in a different way. A "couch potato" is implied to be 'fat', and so Jillian Michaels is talking to a woman on how to stop getting fat, or stop having activities that may induce her to be fat.